# Java FX: refresh a pane after button click (after a node was removed)

Tags: java, animation, javafx

Suppose I have code like this: I create a `Pane`, but `createCell` and `deleteCells` buttons on it. Create another pane and when a `createCell` button is clicked, I add a `Rectangle` to its children list. When a `deleteCells` button is clicked, I remove the `Rectangle`s from the `Pane`'s chilren.

```
public class Main extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> { 
             //Main.java:17)

    private static int cellId=-1;
    private static Cell[] cells = new Cell[100];

    private BorderPane borderPane;
    private Pane cellsPane;
    private Pane buttonsPane;
    private Pane statsPane;

    Button createCellButton;
    Button deleteCellsButton;

    static int  width= 600;
    static int height=400;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");

        borderPane = new BorderPane();
        cellsPane = new Pane();
        buttonsPane = new Pane();
        statsPane = new Pane();

        cellsPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:  #ffffff; -fx-border-color: black");
        buttonsPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:  #f2f2f2; -fx-border-color: black");
        statsPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:  #f2f2f2; -fx-border-color: black");

        createCellButton = new Button();
        deleteCellsButton = new Button();

        createCellButton.setText("Create a cell");
        deleteCellsButton.setText("Delete cells");

        createCellButton.setOnAction(this);
        deleteCellsButton.setOnAction(this);

        buttonsPane.getChildren().add(createCellButton);
        buttonsPane.getChildren().add(deleteCellsButton);

        borderPane.setTop(buttonsPane);

        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(10, 10, 50, 25);
        r.setFill(Color.YELLOW);

        cellsPane.getChildren().add(r);


        borderPane.setCenter(cellsPane);

        statsPane.getChildren().add(new Label("Cells Count: " + cellId +1));
        borderPane.setLeft(statsPane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event)  {
            if (event.getSource()==createCellButton)  {
                    cells[++cellId] = createCell();
                    cellsPane.getChildren().add(cells[cellId].getModel());
                    System.out.println("Cell created: " + cells[cellId].getAge() + ", " + cells[cellId].getColor());
            }
            else if (event.getSource() == deleteCellsButton) {
                    deleteCells(); //Main.java:88
                    System.out.println("Cells deleted");
            }
            else  {
                    System.out.println("Unknown button");
            }
    }

    private Cell createCell()  {
            return new Cell(cellId, width, height);
    }

        private void deleteCells()  {
        for (Cell cell: cells)  {
                System.out.println("removing " + cell.getAge()); 
                                                          //Main.java:102
                cellsPane.getChildren().remove(cell.getModel());
                System.out.println("cell " + cell.getAge() + " removed");
        }
}
```

A `Cell` class:

```
    class Cell  {
        private int age;
        private Color color;
        private Rectangle model;

        public Cell(int id, int width, int height)  {
                age = id;

                Random rand = new Random();

                int x = rand.nextInt(width+1);
                int y = rand.nextInt(height+1);

                color = Color.YELLOW;
                model = new Rectangle(x, y, 50, 25);
                model.setFill(color);
        }

        public Rectangle getModel()  {
                return model;
        }

        public int getAge()  {
            return age;
        }

        public Color getColor()  {
            return color;
        }
}
```

However, after I click `deleteCells`, the previous rectangles are still visible in the window. How do I fix it? How can I refresh the `Pane` after a button was clicked?

**EDIT:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at sample.Main.deleteCells(Main.java:102)
   at sample.Main.handle(Main.java:88)
   at sample.Main.handle(Main.java:17)
```

`System.out.println` output:

```
Cell created: 0, 0xffff00ff
Cell created: 1, 0xffff00ff
Cell created: 2, 0xffff00ff
Cell created: 3, 0xffff00ff
Cell created: 4, 0xffff00ff
Cell created: 5, 0xffff00ff
Cell created: 6, 0xffff00ff
Cell created: 7, 0xffff00ff
Cell created: 8, 0xffff00ff
Cell created: 9, 0xffff00ff
Cell created: 10, 0xffff00ff
removing 0
cell 0 removed
removing 1
cell 1 removed
removing 2
cell 2 removed
removing 3
cell 3 removed
removing 4
cell 4 removed
removing 5
cell 5 removed
removing 6
cell 6 removed
removing 7
cell 7 removed
removing 8
cell 8 removed
removing 9
cell 9 removed
removing 10
cell 10 removed
```

Comment: please provide a complete example (vs. code snippets) - the problem is probably somewhere in the code you are not showing ;)

Comment: @kleopatra Updated the question.

Comment: hmm ... you seem to add the cell's rectangle and remove the cell (not the rectangle). btw: wondering why it compiles, cell not being a node ..

Comment: @kleopatra Thank you! I changed the `deleteCells` to `cellsPane.getChildren().remove(cell.getModel());` and it does remove the rectangulars from the screen. However a run-time error `NullPointerException` arises..

Comment: please update the example here and add the stacktrace

Comment: @kleopatra Updated!

Comment: @kleopatra Figured it out. I declared an array of size `100` and only filled it with several objects, while in `deleteCells` method I loop through all of the array, including its empty part. If you post your answer as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: glad you found it :))